# How to handle minus signs with pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, type-conversion

I went on a journey with pandas when I was trying to read a .csv file that I would like to share with you in the hopes that someone could enlighten me on some of the points. I will mark my questions in bold.

I am using Python 3.8.10 with Pandas version 1.4.4.

So, I have a .csv datafile that I would like to learn how to manipulate with pandas. The data looks like below:

```
time;ax;ay;az;p;
0,171323;0,0000;0,0000;0,0000;0,0000;
0,172043;0,0000;0,0000;0,0000;0,0000;
0,201634;0,0000;0,0000;0,0000;996,4016;
0,228448;0,0000;0,0000;0,0000;996,4016;
0,229615;0,1425;−0,0355;−0,0517;996,4016;
0,237640;0,1425;−0,0355;−0,0517;996,4016;
....
```

and so on. As you can see, the data uses semicolon (;) as a separator and comma (,) as a decimal mark. Additionally, the program where I take the data from adds an extra semicolon at the end of each line. Because of this, I need to load the data with:

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", sep=';', decimal=',', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4])
```

If I then run print(df.dtypes), I get the following output:

```
time    float64
ax       object
ay       object
az       object
p       float64
dtype: object
```

Took me a long time to understand that the problem seems to be that the data is tabulated with the unicode minus character u2212 (−).

**1. Pandas for some reason doesn't recognize this as a minus sign, does someone know why?**

I checked that the type of the elemenets in the ax, ay and az dataseries prints out as <class 'str'>. The task is then to figure out a way of transforming this dataseries to numpy.float64. Calling any of the following:

```
df['ax'] = df['ax'].astype(float)
df['ax'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ax'])
df["ax"] = pd.to_numeric(df["ax"], downcast="float")
```

does not work out of the box and produces a value error of the sort:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,0000'
```

And coercion does not help:

```
df['ax'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ax'], errors='coerce')
```

As this just sets all the dataseries values to NaN.

**2. The problem here seems to be the commas, right? Any hints as to how to do this with the built in methods?**

So I need to find a way of converting the strings to floats. This I can accomplish with:

```
a = []
for i in df["ax"]:
    i = i.replace(',','.')
    i = i.replace(u"\u2212", "-")
    a.append(float(i))

df["ax"] = a
```

But this feels a bit forced and I have to do this for each column separately. I tried writing a method that would accomplish this for me:

```
def replace(df,a):
    """Replace a column in df by array a

    :param df: The dataframe column to be replaced
    :param a: Array in which data is saved
    :return: Nothing
    """
    for i in df:
        i = i.replace(',','.')
        i = i.replace(u"\u2212", "-")
        a.append(float(i))

    df = a
```

But this appears not to work. The values remain unchanged with the problematic unicode character u2212.

**3. Why doesn't the replace method work but doing this type of replacement column by column separately works?**

Putting all of this together, a minimal working example would be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

name = 'accelerometer_log.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(name, sep=';', decimal=',', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4])

a = []
for i in df["ax"]:
    i = i.replace(',','.')
    i = i.replace(u"\u2212", "-")
    a.append(float(i))

df["ax"] = a

df.plot(x="time", y="ax")

plt.show()
```

With this my final question is:

**4. Is there a way to streamline the replacement procedure?**

Any hints or clarifications would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To read the dataframe and convert string to floats you can do:

```py
# read df from csv
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";", dtype=str)
df = df[df.columns[:-1]]

# convert it to floats
df = df.applymap(lambda v: v.replace(",", ".").replace("−", "-")).apply(pd.to_numeric)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       time      ax      ay      az         p
0  0.171323  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000    0.0000
1  0.172043  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000    0.0000
2  0.201634  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  996.4016
3  0.228448  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  996.4016
4  0.229615  0.1425 -0.0355 -0.0517  996.4016
5  0.237640  0.1425 -0.0355 -0.0517  996.4016
```

---

The `df.dtypes` is:

```py
print(df.dtypes)

time    float64
ax      float64
ay      float64
az      float64
p       float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you! I got this to work but with one additional change where the applymap has to be:

`df = df.applymap(lambda v: str(v).replace(",", ".").replace("−", "-")).apply(pd.to_numeric)`

Because otherwise python will print out an attribute error:

`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Other than that, works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper to fix the file before loading it in pandas:

```
from io import StringIO

def fix_minus(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return StringIO(f.read().replace('−', '-'))
    
    
df = (pd.read_csv(fix_minus('filename.csv'), sep=';', decimal=',')
        .iloc[:, :-1]
      )
```

`df`:

```
       time      ax      ay      az         p
0  0.171323  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000    0.0000
1  0.172043  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000    0.0000
2  0.201634  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  996.4016
3  0.228448  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  996.4016
4  0.229615  0.1425 -0.0355 -0.0517  996.4016
5  0.237640  0.1425 -0.0355 -0.0517  996.4016
```

`df.dtypes`:

```
time    float64
ax      float64
ay      float64
az      float64
p       float64
dtype: object
```